# Conectar menu de 5 botones a una vista, con un solo segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, views

Como hacer para emplear un solo segue(1 segue para 5 botones) en vez de 5 segues(1 por boton)  dejando uno solo,que contenga todos los IBAaction y te lleve a la otra vista dependiendo de lo que presiones, el contenido en la otra vista se presenta de una manera u otra.

He estado intentando el siguiente codigo pero sin resultado.

Origen

```
    @IBAction func abstractionENG(sender: UIButton) { return performSegueWithIdentifier("menuENG", sender: nil) } 

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) { 
if(segue.identifier == "menuENG")
{ if let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DefinitionViewController{ 
destinationViewController.tittle = DiccioModel.abstraction().nameEng destinationViewController.def = DiccioModel.abstraction().descriptionEng destinationViewController.link = DiccioModel.abstraction().linkEng } }
```

[image: origen]

Destino

```
import UIKit

class DefinitionViewController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var name:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bodyText:UITextView!
    var tittle:String!
    var def:String!
    var link:String!

    /*This IBAction activates hyperlink to Wikipendia */

    @IBAction func linkToWiki(sender: UIButton) {
        if let url = NSURL(string: link) { UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url) }
    }

    var definition : DiccioModel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.definition = DiccioModel.webBrowser()

        self.name.text = tittle
        self.bodyText.text = def



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


     // End of the code...
}



//
```

[image: DEstino]

Alguien tiene alguna manera de hacerlo como lo solicito o podria orientarme? he intenando de varias formas en codigo sin resultado

PD: he identificado cada boton en el IDentity inspector con numeros para implementarlos en el sender pero tampoco logro el resultado. 
PD: Estoy nivel Rookie en esto asi que si pudieran ser aclarativos seria buenisimo :)  Saludos

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a SOes. Te invito a [edit] tu pregunta y poner el codigo en vez de una imagen, para que podamos ayudarte mejor. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias lo hare

Comment: tengo una situación parecida, tienes el modelo que me lo dejes ver?
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gracias por las consideraciones todas las tome en cuenta y me ayudaron a solucionar. Emplee el siguiente código :

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

/* The following functions containts a group of conditionals which will change the scene depending  of the IBAction selected */

@IBAction func abstractionENG(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = [DiccioModel.abstraction().nameEng,DiccioModel.abstraction().descriptionEng,DiccioModel.abstraction().linkEng]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menuENG", sender: data)
}

@IBAction func webBrowserENG(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = [DiccioModel.webBrowser().nameEng,DiccioModel.webBrowser().descriptionEng,DiccioModel.webBrowser().linkEng]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menuENG", sender: data)
}

@IBAction func latencyENG(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = [DiccioModel.latency().nameEng,DiccioModel.latency().descriptionEng,DiccioModel.latency().linkEng]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menuENG", sender: data)
}

@IBAction func conditionalENG(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = [DiccioModel.conditional().nameEng,DiccioModel.conditional().descriptionEng,DiccioModel.conditional().linkEng]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menuENG", sender: data)
}


@IBAction func operatingSystemENG(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = [DiccioModel.os().nameEng,DiccioModel.os().descriptionEng,DiccioModel.os().linkEng]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menuENG", sender: data)
}

@IBAction func abstractionESP(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = [DiccioModel.abstraction().nameEsp,DiccioModel.abstraction().descriptionEsp,DiccioModel.abstraction().linkEsp]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menuESP", sender: data)
}

@IBAction func webBrowserESP(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = [DiccioModel.webBrowser().nameEsp,DiccioModel.webBrowser().descriptionEsp,DiccioModel.webBrowser().linkEsp]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menuESP", sender: data)
}

@IBAction func latencyESP(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = [DiccioModel.latency().nameEsp,DiccioModel.latency().descriptionEsp,DiccioModel.latency().linkEsp]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menuESP", sender: data)
}

@IBAction func conditionalESP(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = [DiccioModel.conditional().nameEsp,DiccioModel.conditional().descriptionEsp,DiccioModel.conditional().linkEsp]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menuESP", sender: data)
}


@IBAction func operatingSystemESP(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = [DiccioModel.os().nameEsp,DiccioModel.os().descriptionEsp,DiccioModel.os().linkEsp]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menuESP", sender: data)
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "menuENG") || (segue.identifier == "menuESP"){
        if let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DefinitionViewController{
            if let data = sender as? Array<String>{
                destinationViewController.tittle = data[0]
                destinationViewController.def = data[1]
                destinationViewController.link = data[2]
            }
        }
    }



}
```

PS: Este código es el de controlador principal es decir de la vista donde estan los botones y a su vez DestinationViewController, es el destino de la información a donde va todo a través ves del segue cuando presionas un botón en la categoría ingles o español.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que tienes que hacer es asignar un valor a la propiedad tag de cada botón, de forma que tengas boton1.tag=1, boton2.tag=2..... Esto lo haces cuando definas el botón.
Cuando hagas el prepareForSegue, te viene el botón pulsado en sender. lo casteas a UIButton y de ahí sacas el tag. Sabiendo el tag sabes que botón han pulsado y después una vez creado el nuevo controlador tienes que pasarle el botón pulsado y el nuevo controlador, sabiendo que han pulsado hará lo que tenga que hacer. Para esto necesitas una propiedad (o lo mismo con las que tienes creadas de tittle, def y link te sirven) y le pones los valores que necesites. Creo que lo que quieres es que depende del botón que pulses pasar un tittle, def y link diferente. Eso lo haces en el prepareForSegue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject? { 
if(segue.identifier == "menuENG"){
   if let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DefinitionViewController { 

//aquí casteo el sender a un UIButton
if let b = sender as? UIBUtton {
    //ahora puedo saber que botón pulsaron si le asigne el tag en su momento
    switch b.tag {
    case 1:
           destinationViewController.tittle = El que sea    
           destinationViewController.def = el que sea
           destinationViewController.link = el que sea
    case 2:
           destinationViewController.tittle = El que sea    
           destinationViewController.def = el que sea
           destinationViewController.link = el que sea

   .......
   }
}
}
```

Si solo le pasas el botón pulsado y el otro controlador se busca la vida, pues lo dicho le pones una propiedad al segundo controlador de tipo Int y le pasas en el valor del tag (que es el botón pulsado) para que se busque la vida

```
destinationViewController.botonPulsado = b.tag
```

(habiendo casteado el sender a UIButton como te he puesto arriba)

Comment: Saludos he probado ese metodo y me ha funcionado con algunos cambios, pero por requisitos del proyecto alfinal termine cambiando la dinamica.